# multirow:how to deal with the text higher than the row height

Tags: tabularx, multirow

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.6cm,headsep=1mm,headheight=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|X<{\centering}|c|c|c|c|c|p{35mm}<{\centering}|}
    \hline
            &&&&&&&&&100\%&continueous&&worker& \\
            \cline{10-13}
            &&&&\multirow{-2}*{suface quality}&&&\multirow{-2}{60mm}{The financials crashed and burned during the 2008 meltdown but have since been in recovery mode with the rest of the market.  This article will explore the risks and rewards associated with these Financial ETFs to identify which have been the best performers.}&\multirow{-2}*{check}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{SPDR SP Bank ETF}&&worker&\multirow{-2}{30mm}{The Best Financial ETFs} \\
            \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: the layout is terrible]

show as the above code ,the merged row is two while the text in the cell is more than two.the text height in the cell is higher than row height,how to correct it? anyone can help me?thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you want it to look like? The table will get higher for sure, but what about the two rows stuff like "check". Should that stay on the current hight or stay centred?

Comment: You have not indicated how all the various columns are to be vertically aligned.  However, in your MWE, changing just the `\multirow{-2}{60mm}` to `\parbox[t]{60mm}` may or may not be what you eventually desire.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes \parbox[t]{60mm} is not the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[landscape,hmargin=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.6cm,headsep=1mm,headheight=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{7}{c|}C|*{5}{c|}p{35mm}|}
    \hline
    &&&&\multirow{5}*{suface quality}&&&\multirow{5}{\hsize}{The financials crashed and burned during the 2008 meltdown but have since been in recovery mode with the rest of the market. This article will explore the risks and rewards associated with these Financial ETFs to identify which have been the best performers.}&\multirow{5}*{check}&\SI{100}{\percent}&continueous&&worker& \multirow{5}{\hsize}{The Best Financial ETFs} \\\cline{10-13}
    &&&&&&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}*{SPDR SP Bank ETF}}&&\multirow{3}*{worker}& \\
    &&&&&&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&&&\\
    &&&&&&&&&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&&&\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer,it's a good solution,but can it be better?because i don't know the text will occupy know how many rows in advance.so with this method,i must adjust several times to get a good layout.